# link_to with additional html within anchor tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-mobile

How do I add additional content to a link when using the link_to helper in Rails?

```
link_to "Stephen Weber", "index.html"
```

creates this:

```
<a href="index.html">Stephen Weber</a>
```

But what if I want to create this?

```
<a href="index.html">
    <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
    <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
    <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
</a>
```

I'm playing around with jQuery Mobile and this is what is required for formatting content in lists.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You Could do:

```
 <%= link_to 'index.html', :title => "Some link" do %>
     <h3> Stephen Weber </h3>
     ...
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you. I feel so stupid. I forgot you could pass in a block. I'll eventually learn this stuff especially with the awesome support of the community!

Comment: I had to change "<%= link_to" to "<% link to" to avoid compilation error, FYI.